# Sorting all tables on a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I need to sort each table in a worksheet with the same criteria. I use the code below but it gets stuck on line 3

```
Dim tbl As ListObject

For Each tbl In Sheets("Back Table").ListObjects

With Sheets("Back Table").ListObjects(tbl)
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(tbl & "[Home]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(tbl & "[ID]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
End With

Next tbl
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us better explanation of what "stuck" means?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what is the error message?

Comment: `With Sheets("Back Table").ListObjects(tbl)` -> `With tbl`

Comment: @FrankBall Sorry, i get a Subscript out of range message

Comment: @hth Thank you, worked a charm

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for each` is looping through all tables (`ListObjects`), in every iteration your variable `tbl` will hold one of the tables - exactly what you need.

Your next statement (the `With ...`) is flawed. `ListObjects` is a `Collection`, and you access a member of a  `Collection` either by *index number* or by *name* - not by an object.

You could change the line to `With Sheets("Back Table").ListObjects(tbl.name)` - but that's completely unnecessary as this would again return the object you have already in `tbl`. Instead, simply change the line to `With tbl`

Update: I didn't want to steal HTH's answer given in the comments - when I read the comments I was just reading a rather useless discussion about `On Error` that is (fortunately) deleted in the meantime.